# Is Hopf lemma is equivalen to Strong Maximum Principle?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I see a proof of **Hopf lemma** by using **Strong Maximum Principle**, [this link Theorem 2.7](http://www.mi.uni-koeln.de/%7Egsweers/pdf/maxprinc.pdf) .  In general, the Strong Maximum Principle is proved using Hopf's Lemma. Does this imply that these two theorems are equivalent in some sense?

Theorem 7 (**Strong Maximum Principle**) Suppose that $L$ is strictly elliptic and that $c \leq 0$. If $u \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\bar{\Omega})$ and $L u \geq 0$ in $\Omega$, then either $u \equiv \sup _{\Omega} u$ or $u$ does not attain a nonnegative maximum in $\Omega$.

Theorem 2.7 (**Hopf's boundary point Lemma**) Suppose that $\Omega$ satisfies the interior sphere condition $^2$ at $x_0 \in \partial \Omega$. Let $L$ be strictly elliptic with $c \leq 0$. If $u \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\bar{\Omega})$ satisfies $L u \geq 0$ and $\max _{\bar{\Omega}} u(x)=u\left(x_0\right)$. Then either $u \equiv u\left(x_0\right)$ on $\Omega$ or
$$
\liminf _{t \downarrow 0} \frac{u\left(x_0\right)-u\left(x_0+t \nu\right)}{t}>0(\text { possibly }+\infty)
$$
for every direction $\nu$ pointing into an interior sphere. If $u \in C^1\left(\Omega \cup\left\{x_0\right\}\right)$ then $\frac{\partial u\left(x_0\right)}{\partial \nu}<0$.